# Multiple charts not loading on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I am implementing multiple charts on the same page in Codeigniter by using Chart Js but only one chart load; my goal is to be able to preset multiple data in my app dashboard page; but when I try to ad multiple chart, only the first chat loads: my Js codes are:

```
// Sales Chart
var salesCanvas = document.getElementById("salesChart");
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Source Sans Pro";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 14;
//Chart.defaults.global.defaultColor = 'red';
var labelData= <?php echo json_encode($label); ?>;
var chartData= <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>

var salesData = {
  labels: labelData,
  datasets: [{
    label: "Sales",
    data: chartData,
    //chart styling
    lineTension: 0,
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'orange',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderDash: [5, 5],
    pointBorderColor: 'orange',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,150,0,0.5)',
    pointRadius: 5,
    pointHoverRadius: 10,
    pointHitRadius: 30,
    pointBorderWidth: 2,
    pointStyle: 'rectRounded'
    //chart styling
  }]
};

var chartOptions = {
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom',
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 80,
      fontColor: 'black'
    }
  }
};

var lineChart = new Chart(salesCanvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: salesData,
  options: chartOptions
});
// /. Sales Chart
  // Expenses Chart
  var expensesCanvas = document.getElementById("expensesChart");
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Source Sans Pro";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 14;
var labelData= <?php echo json_encode($label); ?>;
var chartData= <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>

var expensesData = {
  labels: labelData,
  datasets: [{
    label: "Expenses",
    data: chartData,
    //chart styling
    lineTension: 0,
    fill: false,
    borderColor: 'orange',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderDash: [5, 5],
    pointBorderColor: 'orange',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,150,0,0.5)',
    pointRadius: 5,
    pointHoverRadius: 10,
    pointHitRadius: 30,
    pointBorderWidth: 2,
    pointStyle: 'rectRounded'
    //chart styling
  }]
};

var chartOptions = {
  legend: {
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom',
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 80,
      fontColor: 'black'
    }
  }
};

var lineChart = new Chart(expensesCanvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: expensesData,
  options: chartOptions
});
// /. Expenses Chat
```

I am implementing multiple charts on the same page in Codeigniter by using Chart Js but only one chart load; my goal is to be able to preset multiple data in my app dashboard page; but when I try to ad multiple chart, only the first chat loads: my Js codes are:

Answer (score 0):

```
var lineChart = new Chart(expensesCanvas, {...

var lineChart = new Chart(salesCanvas, {...
```

just try to use another name , replace lineChart = expensesChart and salesChart

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean;